# Cannot change org.springframework-version in STS

Tags: spring, version, spring-tool-suite

I just created a Spring MVC project in STS 3.3.0.RELEASE and just changed the default`<org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>` to `<org.springframework-version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>`, and Eclipse throws errors (see screenshot below). Any clue on how to remove these errors (perhaps the top one is the culprit)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved - http://www.captaindebug.com/2013/03/creating-spring-32-mvc-web-app.html#.Uf7V-WTbrus - quoting the author - *Now, I could have used the fix outlined in my previous blog; however, the Guys at Spring have been busy and now the solution to this problem is to simply upgrade to Spring version 3.2.2-RELEASE*